# React-Native iOS navigator.geolocation stops after period of time in the background

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, react-native

I'm currently building an application that needs to know when a user passes a speed threshold with some accuracy. Right now I'm using React-Native's [geolocation API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html), which does state that it works in the background.

However, after a period of inactivity the application no longer receives updates from the phone and then never begins returning location information again, even after traveling several hundred meters (in an attempt to trigger the 'siginificant change'). If the application is in the foreground, it works fine, but for my usage it should essentially be in the background all the time. I believe this has something to do with iOS's [significant change location service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

A few other things I've attempted:

Mauron85's [background-geolocation plugin](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation)

This seems to work acceptably well in xcode, but never returns a consistent/accurate speed value while actually driving, and also dies after a period of time with no activity, never brought back with a large amount of driving. (iPhone 4s testing right now, I don't know if that has anything to do with it.)

[react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer)

A setTimeout call polls consistently for the location, but is eventually timed out because iOS limits how much background processing an application can have.

Any and all feedback/ideas is appreciated. I'm brand new to react-native development and will take anything.

Comment: I've started making changes to Mauron85's background-geolocation plugin to get the background location watch to run constantly on iOS (app tracks locations for mileage purposes). So far seems to handle Android fine out of the box. Interested to see if anyone has other thoughts